# Replace object property in list

Tags: c++

Just like in the title, I want to iterate through the list and change properties. What I've managed:

using namespace std;

```
class User {
public:
    int id;
    string name;

    User(int id, string name) {
        this->id = id;
        this->name = name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    list<User> users;

    User u1(1, "foo");
    users.push_back(u1);

    for (auto v : users) {
        v.id = 2;
    }

    for (auto v : users) {
        printf("%d\n", v.id);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

unfortunelly after that the `ids` are still `1`. I exptected `2`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is wrong?

This part:

```
for (auto v : users) {
    v.id = 2;
}
```

is wrong. `auto v` copies the `v` and loop body applies the changes to the *copy*. What you want is to work with *references* in the for loop, like so:

```
for (auto& v : users) {
    v.id = 2;
}
```

Notice that this is not required in your loop that uses `printf`, but still preferred, since your `User` objects are not that cheap to copy, especially when `name`s are big